# I having this error InnoDB error number 995 on Wamp Server

Tags: mysql, apache, wamp

I am having this error on wamp server: InnoDB error number 995

Mysql log

> 2019-02-22T23:10:24.230174Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error
>   number 995 in a file operation.
>   2019-02-22T23:10:24.230174Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means that the
>   I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an
>   application request. Retry attempt is made.

from apache_error.log

> [Sat Feb 23 18:20:43.924593 2019] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 9436:tid
>   25000] AH00326: Server ran out of threads to serve requests. Consider
>   raising the ThreadsPerChild setting

I'm using **mysql 5.7.19, PHP 7.0.23, Apache 2.4.27, wamp 3.1.0 64 bit**

Someone can give me some idea how i can solve this problem please?